# What does this error mean "idf vector not fitted"

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is how I am making a call to the TFIDFVectorizer:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
                vocabulary=selected_vocabulary,
                stop_words='english',
                use_idf=True,
                norm=norm,
                tokenizer=self.tokenize,
                lowercase=True,
                smooth_idf=True)
```

and I get this error when I call

```
vectorizer.transform(data_to_vectorize)
```

Error:

```
  File "/root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1305, in transform
    return self._tfidf.transform(X, copy=False)

  File "/root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1024, in transform
    raise ValueError("idf vector not fitted")

ValueError: idf vector not fitted
```

What does this error mean here?

Comment: it means, that you have to call the `fit` method, before you can call the `transform` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to fit the model first (for example build the vocabulary from the data), before you can transform arbitrary text:

```
vectorizer.fit(data_to_vectorize)
X = vectorizer.transform(data_to_vectorize)
```

or

```
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_to_vectorize)
```

Comment: In the tutorial on using `TfidfTransformer()` it says that once you fit the data to the training set you only need to transform the new data, not fit it again. But when you do this it produces the error mentioned in the question, why? [tutorial in question, see "Training a Classifier" section](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)

Comment: The tutorial is right and you shouldn't be getting the error. If you still get it, please post a question with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The issue was I had used the `'tf_transformer` object  from the example when I was supposed to be using `tfidf_transformer` object from the example. MCVE is the way to go, thanks!